# Amsmath split environment changes alignment inside gather

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, split

I am using an amsmath split environment nested in a gather environment in order to obtain a three-lined equation with a single label aligned in center:

```
\documentclass[11pt, english, singlespacing]{MastersDoctoralThesis}    
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font by default
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\begin{split}
C_V = \left( \frac{\partial E}{\partial T} \right)_V\\
=\sum_{\boldsymbol{k},v}\hbar\omega (\boldsymbol{k},v) \frac{\partial n (\omega,T)}{\partial T}\\
=\sum_{\boldsymbol{k},v}k_B \left( \frac{\hbar\omega(\boldsymbol{k},v)}{k_B T} \right)^2 \frac{e^{\hbar\omega/k_B T}}{\left( e^{\hbar\omega/k_B T}-1 \right)^2 }
\label{eqn:heat_capacity}
\end{split}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

However when i compile the code above it results in the equations being aligned to the right. When i remove the nested split environment, equations are aligned to the center, correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The outer `gather` is here useless: you can replace it by `equation`. And if the equations are to be aligned at the equal signs you need `&=`.

Comment: @campa Problem persists even with `equation`. The equations are needed to be aligned to the center, and that is why i tried with `gather` at first.

Comment: @gstefk what exactly do you mean by center and that it does not. Where exactly does not get the `MastersDoctoralThesis` class? BTW: plesae update your MWE such that one can copy it and it should run as is. For example the `\documentclass` is placed in the wrong location. Please help us help you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `gathered` environment nested in `equation`. But I'd rather suggest an alignment with `aligned` nested in equation (two possibilities of alignment).

I took the opportunity to simplify typing the code for partial derivatives, using the `\diff(*)` commands from the `esdiff` package, and improved the placement of exponents after a big parenthesis with `\mathclap` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esdiff} 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \label{eqn:heat_capacity}
    \begin{gathered}
    C_V = \diffp*{E}{T}{V} \\
    =\sum_{\boldsymbol{k},v}\hbar\omega (\boldsymbol{k},v) \diffp{n (\omega,T)}{ T}\\[-0.5ex]
    =\sum_{\boldsymbol{k},v}k_B \left( \frac{\hbar\omega(\boldsymbol{k},v)}{k_B T} \right)^{\mathclap{2}} \frac{e^{\hbar\omega/k_B T}}{\left( e^{\hbar\omega/k_B T}-1 \right)^2 }
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\bigskip

\begin{equation}
    \label{eqn:heat_capacity1}
    \begin{aligned}
    C_V & = \diffp*{E}{T}{V} =\sum_{\boldsymbol{k},v}\hbar\omega (\boldsymbol{k},v) \diffp{n (\omega,T)}{ T}\\[-0.5ex]
     & =\sum_{\boldsymbol{k},v}k_B \left( \frac{\hbar\omega(\boldsymbol{k},v)}{k_B T} \right)^{\mathclap{2}} \frac{e^{\hbar\omega/k_B T}}{\left( e^{\hbar\omega/k_B T}-1 \right)^2 }
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\bigskip

\begin{equation}
    \label{eqn:heat_capacity1}
    \begin{aligned}
    C_V = \diffp*{E}{T}{V}& =\sum_{\boldsymbol{k},v}\hbar\omega (\boldsymbol{k},v) \diffp{n (\omega,T)}{ T}\\[-0.5ex]
     & =\sum_{\boldsymbol{k},v}k_B \left( \frac{\hbar\omega(\boldsymbol{k},v)}{k_B T} \right)^{\mathclap{2}} \frac{e^{\hbar\omega/k_B T}}{\left( e^{\hbar\omega/k_B T}-1 \right)^2 }
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\gathered` within `\equation` environment was exactly what i needed. Also `\diff` command was very useful, i was not aware of this package. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

or this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font by default
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
   \begin{document}
        \begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
        C_V &= \left( \frac{\partial E}{\partial T} \right)_V\\
        &=\sum_{\boldsymbol{k},v}\hbar\omega (\boldsymbol{k},v) \frac{\partial n (\omega,T)}{\partial T}\\
        &=\sum_{\boldsymbol{k},v}k_B \left( \frac{\hbar\omega(\boldsymbol{k},v)}{k_B T} \right)^2 \frac{e^{\hbar\omega/k_B T}}{\left( e^{\hbar\omega/k_B T}-1 \right)^2 }
        \label{eqn:heat_capacity}
        \end{split}
        \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

[image]